# Inheritance in python: "super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)"

Tags: python-2.7, inheritance

```
import math

class Rocket(object):

    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def move_up(self):
        self.y += 1

    def move_rocket(self, x_inc=0, y_inc=1):
        """move rocket by default move in upward direction by 1
        """
        self.x += x_inc
        self.y += y_inc

    def get_distance(self, other_Rocket):
        """calculates distance between current and other rocket
        """            
        return(math.sqrt(((self.x - other_Rocket.x)**2) + (self.y - other_Rocket.y)**2))


class SpaceShuttle(Rocket):

    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, flights_completed=0):
        super().__init__(x, y)
        self.flights_completed = flights_completed

shuttle=SpaceShuttle(2, 3, 10)

print(shuttle)
```

In above code, the derived class is giving following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/sumeedha/PycharmProjects/Basics/classes.py", line 50, in        shuttle=SpaceShuttle(2,3,10)
>     File "/home/sumeedha/PycharmProjects/Basics/classes.py", line 21, in **init**
>       super().**init**(x, y)
>   TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

Answer (score 2):

You're running Python 2, whereas the first argument for `super()`, `type`, isn't optional like in Python 3.
https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#super

You'll need to call `super()` like this:

```
super(SpaceShuttle, self).__init__(x, y)
```

Comment: Thank You
Just now I have done the same 
Thank you again